# How to commit your changes in an open source to Github

Tags: git, github, version-control, open-source, git-branch

I am contributing to an open source and want to commit my changes. I know these steps

1) fork the open source repository

2) push change to a new branch in that repository

3) Click Pull request button in that open source repository with your branch name on right side.

But I didn't know how to perform this second step. Actually I got a VM setup and installed it on my virtual box.

What I did is simply presses fork on their repository and it created a repo in my github account, then I created a branch simply by typing create branch on github site.

Now I don't know how to send my changes to this Newly forked repo on my account in the new branch.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set up git on your computer, clone your forked repository to your machine, make the changes, then commit and push back to GitHub. GitHub has some good apps that make this easier for you. Look here for a step-by-step guide:

https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

Comment: Hey Actually I already had github , I have source code folder in which I am working is related to some other origin , Now I had made my changes in that code ,